# How to use Kafka Connect for Cassandra without Confluent

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How we can use Kafka Connect with Cassandra without using the Confluent frameworks.

Answer (score 8):

Kafka Connect **is** the framework. Confluent only offers *connectors*. If you don't want to use Confluent Open Source (but why wouldn't you?), you can use all those connectors with vanilla Apache Kafka, too.

There are multiple Casandra connectors available: https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Btw: none of the listed Casandra connectors is maintained by Confluent.

Of course, you could also write you own connector or use any other third party connector.

Comment: The basic concept to access the database is using query either SQL/CQL in my case. connect also performs query on database to store data or fetch data. if i build a consumer group one for processing and other for storing it to DB then, one used  for storing  to DB, say DB-Consumer, it's work is to only store data to database that i could easily do using ORM and i will also have full transparency and control over it. So my concern is how it's actually differs from this type of(DB-consumer) consumer with respect to performance and speed.
thanks in advance for your help and assistance on this.

Comment: Connect as a framework takes care of fail-over and you can also run it in distributed mode to scale out you data import/export "job". Thus, Connect is really a "fire and forget" experience. Furthermore, for Connect, you don't need to write any code -- you just configure the connector.

Comment: Confluent cp-kafka-connect does not have cassandra connector

Comment: You can find Cassandra connector on Confluent Hub: https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-cassandra/

Answer (score 5):

The [DataMountaineer Stream Reactor](http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/connectors.html) has a Cassandra Source and Sink solution that can be used with Kafka Connect.

Drop the jar file ([download](http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/install.html#install)) into the Kafka libs folder and then specify your connector as follows:

```
{
"name": "cassandra-NAME",
"config": {
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connector.class": "com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.source.CassandraSourceConnector",
    "connect.cassandra.key.space": "KEYSPACE",
    "connect.cassandra.source.kcql": "INSERT INTO KAFKA_TOPIC SELECT column1, timestamp_col FROM CASSANDRA_TABLE PK timestamp_col",
    "connect.cassandra.import.mode": "incremental",
    "connect.cassandra.contact.points": "localhost",
    "connect.cassandra.port": 9042,
    "connect.cassandra.import.poll.interval": 10000
}}
```

Start Kafka Connect

```
bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties
```

And load the Cassandra Connector into Kafka Connect via the JSON properties file noted above (assuming it has the name connect-cassandra-source.json)

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @config/connect-cassandra-source.json localhost:8083/connectors
```

You will need to create a table that has a timeuuid column as a cluster key. That is described [here](http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/cassandra-source.html).