# Does the Kafka connect provides java driver for Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Similar to jdbc ,elastic search , hdfs, i need the connector for Cassandra in java for Kafka connect , But i cant find any of the connector for Cassandra  in java. I don't know how to use Kafka connect with Cassandra, i have tried other way like writing the Cassandra raw query in consumer group but i don't think it is a way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Implement Kafka connect without confluent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575015/how-to-implement-kafka-connect-without-confluent)

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/tuplejump/kafka-connect-cassandra

Comment: The Datamountaineer Stream Reactors has a Cassandra JAR that includes all dependencies

Answer (score 2):

There's a community Cassandra connector. Check it out here https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Both source and sink are available.